# regular expression to extract a part of string

Tags: php, regex, string

I have following format of transaction from core banking system

```
This is a <test>  and only <test> hope <u> understand
```

from where i want

```
<test><test><u> (along with <>)
```

with simple substring i can do that , but it will be too slow .. is there any way to capture a text between `< and >` using regex functions?

Comment: so you want the value in between the < and > in an array?

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest I can think of is to use `preg_match_all()` and then `join()` the results together to form the final string:

```
function get_bracketed_words($str) 
{
    if (preg_match_all('/<[a-z]+>/', $str, $matches)) {
        return join('', $matches[0]);
    }
    return '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use this, it should not be too slow (Perl code as an example here):

```
while (my $line = <FILE>) {
    my ($request) = ($line =~ /RequestArray:(.*)/);
    next unless $request;
    # here, you can split $requests to sub-pieces using another regex
    # ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry I missed that you require PHP. But it should be easy rewrite in PHP